# Multiple plugins linked to same settings page

Tags: settings-api

I have **several custom plugins** that do very different things but I use on each of them (or almost) the Jenkins and Mantis Rest APIs. For the moment, the API settings (as URL or tokens) are hard coded in the plugin codes, but I would like to centralize this information on a **settings page**.

I found a [good tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-settings-api-build-custom-admin-page/) to add a plugin settings page but it would require a settings page for each plugin when the information would be the same...

Would anyone have a solution?

Comment: How about a global (theme level) options page?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a dedicated settings plugin, which you would use to add single settings page and register separate section and setting for each token/url/etc.

As the settings are saved to the database you can get them with `get_option( 'setting_name' )` in any other plugin whenever you need.

Comment: Yes that's what I've just done, thanks for your answer